# Sum of angles related to a triangle

Tags: geometry

I have got a multiple choice question, which is below:
[image]

and the question is what is value of **x+y**

below are the choices:

1. 180
2. 185
3. 190
4. 195
5. 200

I have tried but not understand how to solve this. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

$(180^{\circ}-y)+(180^{\circ}-125^{\circ})+ x=180^{\circ}$. You can tell $y-x=55^{\circ}$ but can not determine $x+y$ from just what's given.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot determine $x+y$ because, if you have a solution, it suffices that you take CB slightly more vertical, say, and this will result in an increase of both $x$ and $y$!

Answer (score 1):

$$ (180^0 -y) + x = 125^0$$
 $$ y-x = 55^0$$

That is all. The given problem cannot be solved as it is about $(x+y)$

Comment: Though it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 5.

Indeed, from the knowledge of $x-y$ and $x+y$, the possible angles $A,B,C$ are

1. $ 55.0 , 62.5 , 62.5 $
2. $ 55.0 , 60.0 , 65.0 $
3. $ 55.0 , 57.5 , 67.5 $
4. $ 55.0 , 55.0 , 70.0 $
5. $ 55.0 , 52.5 , 72.5 $

and only the last proposal is such that $B<A$ ($C$ closer to $A$ than to $B$).

Comment: May be you mean $ x+y= 185^0?$

Comment: @Narasimham: no, why ?

Comment: This answer relies on the idea the picture depicts accurate proportions (otherwise the actual triangle could have that $C$ isn't closer than $B$ to $A$).

Comment: @JustinBenfield: obviously. As you are told that there is a good answer among the five, then there must be a compatibility condition that you can infer from the picture.